# Callback function not returning?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm learning Node.js and I'm trying to make a site where people can review movies. Everything works so I'm adding a feature that grabs the poster. I have this callback setup but I can't seem to figure out why it isn't working. It logs to the console fine, but nothing returns to the server.

```
function getPoster(title) {
    var dataret;
    imdbId(title, function (err, imdb_id) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log(imdb_id);
            imdb(imdb_id, (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err.stack);
                }
                if (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
                dataret = data;
            });
        }
    });
    return dataret;
}

app.get('/getposter/:id', function (req, res) {
    // IT WORKS UP TO HERE
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.status(200).send({ json: JSON.stringify(getPoster(req.params.id)) });
});
```

Comment: Is `imdbId()` a promise? If it is, your return statement should happen before `dataret` is populated.

Comment: I don't know honestly, I'm new at node sorry :(

Comment: Try changing `dataret = data;` to `return data`.

Comment: I get undefined now once I changed it

Comment: ah also, change `imdbId(title, function (err, imdb_id)` to `return imdbId(title, function (err, imdb_id)`. Apologies!

Comment: I think it's running wrong, it returns the undefined first, and then the id. How can I setup a callback? That's the part that's confusing me.

Comment: `getPoster(req.params.id).then(id=>res.status(200).send({ json: JSON.stringify(id) });`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160108/discussion-between-ryan-knutson-and-mrtig).